# JPQL, getting elementcollections containing two elements on a list and no one that is not on that list

Tags: jpa, jpql

I am trying to generate a query to retrieve some Entity that has two element collection inside with some specific values (as an Enum). The idea is that I want to get all entities that one of its element collection has a specific length of 2 items, and these two items must be included on a provided list.

For example:

```
@Entity
class MyEntity {
  ...
  @ElementCollection
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  @OrderColumn(name = "index")
  private List<Value> elements1 = new ArrayList<>();

  @ElementCollection
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  @OrderColumn(name = "index")
  private List<Value> elements2 = new ArrayList<>();
}

enum Value {
  A,
  B,
  ...
}
```

Then I am trying to use JPA for selecting all entities that includes two 'A' on the element list (on element1 or element2). Not one 'A' and a 'B', not one 'A' on each element list, etc.

What I have done so far is:

```
@Query("SELECT m FROM MyEntity m JOIN m.elements1 e1 JOIN m.elements2 e2 WHERE (" +
            "(size(d.elements1)=2 AND e1 IN :allowedValues AND e1 NOT IN :forbiddenValues) OR " +
            "(size(d.elements2)=2 AND e2 IN :allowedValues AND e2 NOT IN :forbiddenValues)" +
            ") ")
    Set<MyEntity> findByOnlyAllowedValues(@Param("allowedValues") Collection<Value> allowedValues, @Param("forbiddenValues") Collection<Value> forbiddenValues);
```

Where `forbiddenValues` is the values of the enum that are not included on `allowedValues`. Seems that the current query is not working as expected and the retrieved values include:

```
{MyEntity elements1=[A, A], elements2=[]} <<-- Desired.
{MyEntity elements1=[A, B], elements2=[]} <<-- Undesired.
```

But not including:

```
{MyEntity elements1=[B, B], elements2=[]} <<-- Not included. Is correct.
```

Basically, `{MyEntity elements1=[A, B], elements2=[]}` is obtained as has one `A` but must be not obtained as has one `B` (or has only one `A`).

Is it possible to achieve this with JPA? If not, what can be the best approach for a database with hundreds of `MyEntity` without loading the complete database?

Answer (score 0):

The query is returning any entity that contains one `e1` value on the list. As this is how the `JOIN` is working.
To obtain the desired result, I need to change the way of thinking and create a different query as:

```
@Query("SELECT m FROM MyEntity m WHERE ((size(d.elements1)=2 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT s1 FROM d.elements1 e1 WHERE e1 IN :forbiddenValues)) OR (size(d.elements2)=2 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT e2 FROM d.elements2 e2 WHERE e2 IN :forbiddenValues)))) ")
Set<MyEntity> findByOnlyAllowedValues(@Param("forbiddenValues") Collection<Value> forbiddenValues);
```

Checking that no undesired element is present and I have at least 2 elements is enough.